# IOS tableview selection in string format

Tags: ios, swift3, tableview

I have been trying to get the selected value of a tableview cell to next view. But however the value which is being selected and passed to the next view is not which is being selected. The actual selection and the value passed is contradicting. Can anyone Please help me with this. Below is what i am actually trying. The value is being passed through segue to SecondViewController.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow! as NSIndexPath

    let DestViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController

    var SecondTableArrayTwo : MyTable

    SecondTableArrayTwo = SecondArray[indexPath.row]

    DestViewController.SecondArray = SecondTableArrayTwo.MyTitle



    DestViewController.CategorySelected = selected
```

Comment: what is value of `selected`. CategorySelected should be `indexPath.row`

Comment: Please print the value of Second array first, and check the index of the value it SHOULD pass and what it is passing.

Comment: DestViewController.CategorySelected = indexPath.row----this will return me the integer value of selected row. I want in String format(the actual value selected String)@AnkitThakur